# How to use ES6 map function in React stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-map

In my React application, I have an array of objects which I get through an api response. I want to display each object detail in an accordion. I am using react-accessible accordion and have created a React Stateless Component. I want each of my accordion to represent one object of the array. I have my array of objects in dataProp and to iterate over that 
I have written my component like below-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ChildAccordion from './ChildAccordion'
import { setData } from '../actions/action'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';


import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';


class ParentAccordion extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      //call to action
      this.props.setData();
  }

  getMappedData = (dataProp) =>{
      if (dataProp) { 
         return dataProp.map(item =>{
            return <div>{dataProp[item]}</div>
        })
      }
      else {
       return "";
      }
}

    render(){
        const { dataProp } = this.props;
        return (
            // RENDER THE COMPONENT
                <Accordion>
        <AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItemTitle>
                <h3>Details: 
               { 
                this.getMappedData(item[name])
               }

                </h3>
            </AccordionItemTitle>
            <AccordionItemBody>
            <ChildAccordion {...dataProp} />
            </AccordionItemBody>
        </AccordionItem>
    </Accordion>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        dataProp: state.dataProp
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setData(data) {
    dispatch(setData(data));
  }
})
export default connect (mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (ParentAccordion)
```

While doing so, this gives me error-

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined
```

Can someone let me know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing 2 things - first of all, your `getMappedData` method doesn't have a closing curly brace. Secondly, the if condition needs to return a value:

```
getMappedData = (dataProp) =>{
      if (dataProp) { 
        return dataProp.map(item =>{
            return item;
        })
      }
      else {
       return "";
      }
}
```

also, the method call should be `this.getMappedData` not `this.props.getMappedData` because the method is defined on the class and NOT coming in from props

the other issue is, you can't just return an array from the `getMappedData` method, you need to return jsx, so it should probably be something like:

```
getMappedData = (dataProp) =>{
      if (dataProp) { 
        return dataProp.map(item =>{
            return <div>{item}</div>;
        })
      }
      else {
       return "";
      }
}
```

assuming the `item` is a string or number. If it's an object or array it will not work.

also your render method can just use `{this.getMappedData()}` no need for the prop in there, your `getMappedData` method can use the prop:

```
getMappedData() {
      const { dataProp } = this.props;
      if (dataProp) { 
        return dataProp.map(item =>{
            return <div>{item}</div>;
        })
      }
      else {
       return "";
      }
}
```

Comment: I have added the changes but while calling the method I get error - Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined

Comment: can you copy the new code and paste it below your original question - maybe title it 'edit' or something

Comment: your return looks wrong - it shouldn't be `return <div>dataProp[item]</div>` see my code - it should be `<div>{item}</div>` assuming item is not an object

Comment: correct, I modified and added curly braces around, still the same issue :(

Comment: you need to remove the word `dataProp` it's just `<div>{item}</div>` but that may not work if the `item` is an object or array - it needs to be a string or integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181630/discussion-between-duxfox-and-techie-questie).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your initial question:
The dataProp array can simply be rendered in the following manner:

```
  render(){
      const { dataProp } = this.props;

      return <Accordion>
            {
              dataProp && dataProp.map(item =>
              <AccordionItem>
                <AccordionItemTitle>
                  <h3>
                    Details: {item.title}
                  </h3>
                </AccordionItemTitle>
                <AccordionItemBody>
                  {item.body}
                </AccordionItemBody>
              </AccordionItem>
            )}
          </Accordion>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your call `this.props.getMappedData(item[name])` to `this.getMappedData(item[name])`

The reason it can't find that is props are generally used to pass data from parent to child. This blog post does a great job of explaining it. [https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17](http://Passing%20Data%20Between%20React%20Components)

Comment: My bad, it was a typo. I am using this.getMappedData(item[name]) only. Edited the post.Thanks for pointing out.